# Temporarily change tint color after globally changing the tint color in the application delegate

Tags: ios, swift, colors, themes

My iOS app's color theme is used to set the app's global `tint colors`. However, in some cases this results in white text on a white background (which I would like to avoid). Is there a way that I could temporarily change my global `tint color` (or set a specific `tint color` for that instance)?

The two `tint colors` in particular that I would like to change within the app are:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor
```

Specifically, I would like to change the tint color in a situation where I do not have direct access to the view (such as, when I use UIActivityViewController to share an article and the notes' dialog "cancel" and "save" buttons are white-on-white).

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following link to get a better understanding of tintColor.

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming

You can override the global tint colors in a specific view controller for a specific component.

For example if you set the global tint color for UIButton to blueColor, you can do this in your view controller to override the tintColor

```
myButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned in my question, but my problem is how the tint color is being applied to system views (such as when I use UIActivityViewController to share to my notes) where I don't have direct access to the button tint colors.

Comment: @AbbyThompson In that case do this
`myActivityController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

for system view where you donot have access to the views, you can do somehing like this
`let subviews = myView.subviews()

for (view in subviews)
{
    view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor
}`

Comment: Just tried it. Sadly, that code changes the tint of my subviews but doesn't change the the tint of the system views :(

Comment: Same with me and cannot find the solution. Have you found the way? :)